# How to access the List which is placed inside the dictionaries in python

Tags: python-2.7

ex.

```
{'positions': {u'_total': 1, u'values': [{u'startDate': {u'year': 2000, u'month': 7}, u'title': u'ABCD', u'company': {u'industry': u'ABCD', u'size': u'1001-5001', u'type': u'ABCD', u'id': 1234, u'name': u'ABCD'}, u'summary': u'ABCD', u'isCurrent': , u'id': }]}
```

I am trying to access "comapny" dictionary

Comment: Your sample is not actually valid Python. Can you please provide us with an actual valid Python structure? And accessing nested objects is rather trivial, where did you get stuck?

Comment: And what should happen if there are multiple dictionaries in the `d['positions']['values']` list?